# Oracle - grouping values along interval

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, lead

I need to query a table, containing a step id + value.
The result will list the intervals, along with their associated value.
Intervals here are defined as "succession of contiguous ids of steps, sharing same data value".

I'm having a hard time describing it in words, so please see this:

From this table

```
  Step ! Data
  ------------
   1   !  A
   2   !  A
   3   !  A
   5   !  A
   6   !  B
  10   !  A
```

I need the following report

```
  From ! To   ! Data
  -------------------
     1 !   3  !   A
     5 !   5  !   A
     6 ! null !   B
    10 ! null !   A
```

I thought lead() would help me out here, but did not succeed.

Comment: It seems the data is considered separately for values A and B? Then: Why is the result (5, 5) for that row, but then (6, NULL) and not (6, 6)?

Comment: Oh...  so, for the LAST occurrence of each "Data" value, the interval should be open-ended, but all other intervals are "close-ended"?

Comment: You got it right, still this is kinda over-specified: "To" values showing identical as "From" instead of NULL is perfectly acceptable

Comment: If we would also have `A ! 11` would you like the last range to be '10 ! null` or `10 ! 11'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      min (step)                                                   as "from"
           ,nullif (max (step),max(min(step)) over (partition by data))  as "to"
           ,data

from       (select      step,data
                       ,row_number () over (partition by data order by step) as n

            from        t
            ) 

group by    data
           ,step - n            

order by    "from"
```

Comment: The sample result, shouldn't it have `5 !   null !   A` instead of  `5 !   5  !   A`?

Comment: NULL would only indicate the last open interval. As you can see, for value A, a new interval is starting at step 10, that's why then interval starting at 5 is ending there too.

Comment: Please add 'A ! 11` to the result set and then compare the solutions

Comment: Thank you so much @Dudu Markovitz, your solution fills exactly my initial need - the null values indeed bring useful information for open-ended intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by generating a sequence of numbers and subtracting from the `step`.  This will be a constant when the values are sequential:

```
select min(step) as from_step, max(step) as to_step, data
from (select t.*,
            row_number() over (partition by data order by step) as seqnum
     from t
    ) t
group by (step - seqnum), data;
```

EDIT:

It is not quite clear where the `NULL`s are coming from.  If I speculate that they are the last values for each value, you can do:

```
select min(step) as from_step,
       (case when max(step) <> max_step then max(step) end) as to_step,
       data
from (select t.*,
             max(step) over (partition by data) as max_step
             row_number() over (partition by data order by step) as seqnum
     from t
    ) t
group by (step - seqnum), data, max_step;
```

Comment: The OP didn't explain it very well, but it seems the data is partitioned by value (look at steps 5-6).

Comment: @mathguy . . . That is what this solution does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff shoudn't `row_number` be `partition by data` or at least use `data` in `order` claues?

Comment: Wow, that was fast - and efficient

Comment: Putting `data` in the `row_number()` is definitely an option.  It is not required in this case because the steps seem to be a monotonically increasing sequence.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Imagine 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 with the "Data" values A,A,B,B,A,A. Here 1, 2, 5, 6 will be grouped together.

Comment: <clumsyNewbieCommenting>Wow, that was fast - and efficient ! I tried your suggestion and it fits the needs pretty good. This does not provide null value for unterminated intervals though, but I can easily cope with that  </clumsyNewbieCommenting>

Comment: BS. He didn't change the question; a_horse changed a tag.

Comment: Not sure what OP change you're referrring to ? Don't have currently test data for mathguy's point, but if confirmed, yes, this would be an issue for the purpose

Comment: Wrong results in case the last range has more than 1 element

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . The comparison of the max steps should work regardless of how many steps are in the last range.

Comment: A sepcial warm thanks to @Gordon Linoff: your edited version works like a charm - only I had to add an else statement to the to_step column statement. Cheers to all, this community is awesome !

Comment: Am allowed to notify only one at a time, so here my thx to @mathguy too for detecting the excess grouping

Comment: No, this puts null even for close range

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . The last two ranges are open in the OP's example.  I'm not sure what a "close range" would be.